# Set DatePicker Value With Result from MySQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, datepicker

I want to set the text inside a date picker to the result of an SQL query. I do the following to get the date;

```
deadlineDatePrompt = rs.getString("Deadline");
```

This obviously stored the date as a String. I try to set the value of my DatePicker using;

```
deadlineDatePicker.setText(deadlineDatePrompt);
```

This however does not work as setText isn't defined for DatePicker. Changing `setText()` to `setValue()` does not work either as `deadlineDatePrompt` is stored as a string. Changing it to a `LocalDate` does not fix the issue as then `rs.getString` does not work.

Is there a work around for this so that I can get the result of the date set inside my database and display it inside the DatePicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the value from the database as a `java.sql.Date`. A `DatePicker` requires a `java.time.LocalDate`, so you need to convert it: this is pretty easy as `java.sql.Date` defines a [`toLocalDate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--) method.

So

```
java.sql.Date deadlineDatePrompt = rs.getDate("Deadline");
deadlineDatePicker.setValue(deadlineDatePrompt.toLocalDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read 'Deadline' field as a date using [getDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28java.lang.String%29):

```
 rs.getDate("Deadline");
```

Be aware that get Date return java.sql.Date not java.util.Date so you need to convert one to another.

Comment: In doing this `deadlineDatePicker.setValue(deadlineDatePrompt); ` now doesn't work as it is not applicable for Date.

Comment: You should convert java.sql.Date to java.util.Date or also you can do  rs.getTimestamp("Deadline"); that should return a java.sql.Date

Comment: You need to convert it to a `java.time.LocalDate`, not a `java.util.Date`.